# Make active block not hidden after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, scrollbar

Well, I am making a simple left panel menu. What I want to do is to make sub-menu visible even after refresh when the category is active.

Example:

```
-Users

-Dashboard

-Blog
-----articles
-----new article
```

I am on articles si I can see entire submenu even after refreshing of the website.

I make it works this way.

Handlebars menu

```
   <div class="blog-tab {{#if active.blog}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}" id="blog-tab">
            <a>
                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>Blog
                <i class="fas fa-caret-down admin-panel-item-dropdown"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="blog-sub-tab" class="toggleable-tab">
            <div class="sub-toggleable-tab">
                <div class="{{#if active.posts}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><a
                        href="/admin/articles/1">Articles</a></div>
                <div class="{{#if active.newPost}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><a
                        href="/admin/create/article">Create new article</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eshop-tab {{#if active.eshop}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}" id="eshop-tab">
            <a><i class="fas fa-store"></i>Eshop
                <i class="fas fa-caret-down admin-panel-item-dropdown"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="eshop-sub-tab" class="toggleable-tab">
            <div class="sub-toggleable-tab">
                <div class="{{#if active.eshopCatalog}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><a
                        href="/admin/catalog">Catalog</a></div>
                <div class="{{#if active.createNewProduct}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}"><i
                        class="fas fa-circle"></i><a href="/admin/create/product">Create new product</a></div>
                <div class="{{#if active.eshopOrders}}admin-panel-active-tab{{/if}}"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><a
                        href="/admin/orders/1">Orders</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Handlebars make it scrolled.

```
{{#if active.blog}}
<script>$("#blog-sub-tab").slideToggle(0);</script>
{{/if}}
{{#if active.eshop}}
<script> $("#eshop-sub-tab").slideToggle(0);</script>
{{/if}}
```

I am passing to every subcategory active.blog or active.tab so it's easy.
But now I am using webpack and cant use jquery when its frontend rendered.
Yes, it can be fixed... But I am looking for any better way how to do it.
That can be done only in js(with jquery) without handlebars. Thank for any help.

Comment: something like `{{#if active.posts}}` OR `{{#if active.newPost}}` THEN assign class `expanded` to `<div class="sub-toggleable-tab">`. Once that element has class `expanded`, you can even handle its auto-opening in CSS

Comment: @GrafiCode Ou yes i understand thank you very much :D